# NSTextView with automatic fitting to content size

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsattributedstring, nstextview

Main problem:

SwiftUI's `Text()` have no ability to fill large amounts of text inside. In case of text have too many symbols or in case of too large font it's displaying the following error:

> [Window] Warning: Window SwiftUI.AppKitWindow 0x13be8e970 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
> 2023-08-19 22:48:49.743611+0300 Videq[83718:3987311] -[<_TtCOCV7SwiftUI11DisplayList11ViewUpdater8PlatformP33_65A81BD07F0108B0485D2E15DE104A7514CGDrawingLayer: 0x6000031d8e40> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (479.000000, 323046.000000), contentsScale 2.000000, backing store size (958.000000, 646092.000000)
> 2023-08-19 22:48:49.791437+0300 Videq[83718:3987311] Metal API Validation Enabled

So I need to write custom `Text()` using `NSTextView`

myCode is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct AttributedText2: View {
    @Binding var text: AttributedString
    
    var nsText: Binding<NSAttributedString> {
        Binding(get: { NSAttributedString(text) }, set: { _ in })
    }
    
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0
    
    public var body: some View {
        AttributedTextInternal(attributedString: nsText)
    }
}

//@available(OSX 11.0, *)
//public struct AttributedText: View {
//    @Binding var text: NSAttributedString
//
//    public init(attributedString: Binding<NSAttributedString>) {
//        _text = attributedString
//    }
//
//    public var body: some View {
//        AttributedTextInternal(attributedString: $text)
//    }
//}

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct AttributedTextInternal: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: NSAttributedString
    
    public init(attributedString: Binding<NSAttributedString>) {
        _text = attributedString
    }
    
    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustTextFld {
        let textView = CustTextFld()
        
        textView.setContent(text: text, makeNotEditable: true)
        
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        textView.layerContentsPlacement = .top
        textView.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .crossfade
        
        return textView
    }
    
    public func updateNSView(_ textView: CustTextFld, context: Context) {
        textView.setContent(text: text, makeNotEditable: true)
    }
}

public class CustTextFld: NSTextView {
    func setContent(text: NSAttributedString, makeNotEditable: Bool) {
        self.isEditable = true
        
        self.selectAll(nil)
        self.insertText(text, replacementRange: self.selectedRange())
        
        self.isEditable = !makeNotEditable
    }
    
    // remove cursor
    public override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    }
    
    public override func viewWillDraw() {
        isHorizontallyResizable = true
        isVerticallyResizable = true
        isRichText = true
        isSelectable = false
        
//        isRichText = false
    }
    
    public override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        
        NSColor.white.setStroke()
        
        path.stroke()
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString {
    func height(containerWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: containerWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.size.height)
    }

    func width(containerHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: containerHeight),
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.size.width)
    }
}
```

issue here that I'm to able to force size of `AttributedText2` for being sure that it's width and height will be correct:

- width must be the same as parent's view content
- height must be calculated from width using `NSAttributedString.height(containerWidth: )`

I had tried to get content size but didn't have any results. Also I have tried to do `textView.sizeToFit()` - also no results.

Tried to use Geometry reader to get view width - but it's breaking the view and view still have incorrect size.

So code:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    AttributedTextInternal(attributedString: nsText)
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nsText.wrappedValue.height(containerWidth: geometry.size.width))
}
```

doesn't work on large texts. Try to set text with 20 000 words and to locate `AttributedText2()` inside of `ScrollView()`

Is anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## Attempt #2

This is super simple but it seems from your comment this might be what you are looking for: `Text()` might actually work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let height = 300.0
    let words: String = (1...10000).map { "Word\($0)" //The 10,000 you mentioned
    }.joined(separator: " ")

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(words)
                .font(.body) // Customize the font if you want to do that
                .padding()
        }.frame(height: height)
    }
}
```

`let height` is how tall you want the text area to be.

[This gif](https://imgur.com/a/NLA7Be4) shows it working.

## Ignore below!

If I understand you correctly, then I think this solves it. All you have to do is replace the `AttributedText2` struct with the following:

```
public struct AttributedText2: View {
    @Binding var text: AttributedString
    
    var nsText: Binding<NSAttributedString> {
        Binding(get: { NSAttributedString(text) }, set: { _ in })
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            AttributedTextInternal(attributedString: nsText)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nsText.wrappedValue.height(containerWidth: geometry.size.width))
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that it uses `GeometryReader` for the size data. When integrated, it simply becomes:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct AttributedText2: View {
    @Binding var text: AttributedString
    
    var nsText: Binding<NSAttributedString> {
        Binding(get: { NSAttributedString(text) }, set: { _ in })
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            AttributedTextInternal(attributedString: nsText)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nsText.wrappedValue.height(containerWidth: geometry.size.width))
        }
    }
}


@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct AttributedTextInternal: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: NSAttributedString
    
    public init(attributedString: Binding<NSAttributedString>) {
        _text = attributedString
    }
    
    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustTextFld {
        let textView = CustTextFld()
        
        textView.setContent(text: text, makeNotEditable: true)
        
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        textView.layerContentsPlacement = .top
        textView.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .crossfade
        
        return textView
    }
    
    public func updateNSView(_ textView: CustTextFld, context: Context) {
        textView.setContent(text: text, makeNotEditable: true)
    }
}

public class CustTextFld: NSTextView {
    func setContent(text: NSAttributedString, makeNotEditable: Bool) {
        self.isEditable = true
        
        self.selectAll(nil)
        self.insertText(text, replacementRange: self.selectedRange())
        
        self.isEditable = !makeNotEditable
    }
    
    // remove cursor
    public override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    }
    
    public override func viewWillDraw() {
        isHorizontallyResizable = true
        isVerticallyResizable = true
        isRichText = true
        isSelectable = false
        
//        isRichText = false
    }
    
    public override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        
        NSColor.white.setStroke()
        
        path.stroke()
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString {
    func height(containerWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: containerWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.size.height)
    }

    func width(containerHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: containerHeight),
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.size.width)
    }
}
```

What is looks like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tried it. It's doesn't work on large texts. Try to set text with 20 000 words and to locate `AttributedText2()` inside of `ScrollView()`. You will not be able to scroll down :) But thanks for a try

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA I updated my answer given what you said. It holds 10,000 words and I think it fits your criteria. Let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: `Text()` is not solution for me because of error written in my question. Try to set font size to 100 and you will see the same error.  Try to write much more words and you will see the same error. Just like written on the beginning of my question

Comment: found solution for my case

Answer (score 0):

Resolved limitation of Text() with the following code:

```
struct ParagraphedText: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let paragraphs = text.split(separator: "\n")
            
            ForEach(paragraphs, id:\.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ParagraphedText2: View {
    @Binding var paragraphs: [AttributedString]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(paragraphs, id:\.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So error will be throwned only in case of no paragraphs in the text. It's OK for me.